# stop ringtone after delay

Tags: android

i want to stop the ringtone of incoming call after delay of time...is it possible?

thanks

Comment: i dont have any idea,therefore i want  your help

Comment: the first google it  or search same kind of question on Stack Overflow and then ask, may be you can find the same type of question, so why to wait for answer if you find the same question.

Comment: i tried to find however without success, i dont find how to stop ringtone after delay of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Timer or a TimerTask.
However, I would recommend you to use a Handler for that matter, and post a delayed message to trigger the disered event:
sendMessageDelayed(android.os.Message, long)

hope it helps!

```
        MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
        Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(myTask, DELAY_TIME_IN_MILISECONDS, 10000);
```

And the TimerTask implementation:

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
      public void run() {
             //STOP YOUR RINGTONE
             myTimer.cancel();
             myTimer=null;
      }
    }
```

Comment: hi thanks for help! maybe can you post the code?i did a function which recognize that the phone is ringing,how can i stop the ringtone after delay of time?thanks in advance

Comment: then you should upload that code part in the question, that helps better

Comment: No, I should not. The one who asked should have done some research before asking such a trivial question. He has not even tried anything. We are not here to give chewed code to anyone.

Comment: @Lucifer ,  I am sorry for my mood, but just take a look at this question I made, and you will understand my frustration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567552/how-to-programatically-connect-2-android-devices-with-wifi

Comment: @Perroloco, my bad, i was telling that part to OP, not to you friend. And +1 for answer with example.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, Use Timer or you can also use thread. If the user not enable to receive a call and ring is going on, then after a specific time that you set, you can stop ringing. Just search :How to use timer in android, it is very simple code and easy to understand. It will solve your problem.